# Arrow alignment issue

Tags: jquery, html

[Issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvNtO.png)

[image]

I have a div which contains 8 sections and the sections are dynamically generating. Due to the size, only 5 will display in a row. So my issue is for the first row the arrow is displaying correctly just below the individual sections whereas for the remaining sections, the arrow is not coming to the second row it's moving out of the div width in the first row itself. Total width of the div is 675px; And the each section width is 120px. Sometimes the row might be more than 2 rows. So expecting a common fix.

Code:

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

```js
$scope.showData = function (item, index) {      
    var indexno = index;
    var leftpos = (indexno * 120);
    $('.' + item).addClass('active').removeClass('hide').removeClass('ng-hide');
    $('.' + item).siblings('.handset_view').removeClass('active').addClass('hide');
    $('.' + item).parent().siblings('.arrow').css('left', leftpos);
}
```

Attached the image. I selected Galaxy J3 (2016) and the arrow is not below the selected item instead it is displaying out of the div.

Comment: 120*5 = 600px. so anyhow only 5 will come in a row. decrease each container width a bit more. Also image width and text width need to be 100% (equal to container div width)

Comment: Due to some reasons I can't reduce the container width. Need to display the arrow down to the selected section. If a user selects a section from the second row the arrow should display below the particular section row.